# windows 8.1 0 10Gb of RAM shows 3.49 gb as usable

Tags: windows-8.1, memory, performance

My PC already have a 2gb ram in slot 1 and added a new 8gb to slot 2 but after booting it shows only 3.49 gb as available memory(I also checked it with speccy app). I checked msconfig options and the max memory is unchecked. How do I fix it?

Comment: I sent the model number to the seller and he said there's nothing wrong with my motherboard and ram.

Comment: This question already has an answer on this site.

Comment: Do you have a 32bit OS?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 32 bit version, 3.5 GB is the limit of the address space, there is no fix possible.
You need to get 64 bit Windows to use all the memory; that's why 64 bit Windows came out (not the only reason though)

Comment: I disagree, it states that there is no fix, because it is a hard limit for 32 bit systems. What else could the answer be (assuming this is not incorrect)?

Comment: Then how come 32-bit linux doesn't suffer from this 'hard limit'? :)

Comment: @jiggunjer, although 4GB is the theoretical limit of 32 bit address space, the question was about *Windows*, which - in the 32-bit editions - is internally architected so it cannot use more than 3.5 GB RAM memory.